# dynamically adding cards to the screen after sending a post request to database in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, get, request

I want to refresh my `cardData` array that gets its value by a get request from the database after I send a post request the the database. I have written this `saveDraft()` function that upon click adds values to `cardData` array but I need to refresh the page or click on it twice to see the changes. Is there a way to do it dynamically without refreshing the page?

```
    saveDraft() {
      Api.createComment({
          // it's a post request
        })
        .then(res => {
          if (response.status == 200) {
            Api.getComments().then(res => {
              // it's a get request to update the cardData
              if (res.status === 200) {
                this.cardData = res.data;
              } else {
                // catches error
              }
            });
          } else {
            // catches error
          }
        });
    },
```

Comment: Please provide relevant template code also?

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly see how you've implemented the saveDraft() function but I'll work with what you gave!

To generally answer your question, I think it depends on what you mean by clicking on it twice or refreshing the page (i.e. 'clicking' meaning you've bound it to a user event such as @dblclick or @click?). But in Vue, you can handle dynamic events through the following:

**1)** Is this function in a child component? If yes, then consider using [v-on directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) to listen to user events (i.e. `@dblclick`, `@click`, `@mouseover`, etc.), emitting a [custom event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html), or creating a `watcher` that 'updates' the data in a parent.

- If this is confusing, you can check out the video by Vue Mastery on [event handling](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/intro-to-vue-js/communicating-events/) that goes over the foundations of emitting events from the child component to the parent.

**2)** You can consider using Vuex as a state-manager. This can help with reactivity - of updating a component or piece of data being passed around through mutations and actions. Check out a [general overview of Vuex and reactivity in Vue on Vue Mastery](https://www.vuemastery.com/courses/mastering-vuex/intro-to-vuex/)

If this *still* doesn't make sense, let me know here or update your question if needed :)